# Common Column Names from Multiple Tables MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i have multiple tables of products like product_shirt, product_pants etc and on top of it there is a general product table. Anyways i have came to a situation where i need to make a UNION query by selecting some fields from all the tables that are common like . color field is both in shirts and pants and bags etc ...

Is there any query for getting column names that exist in multiple tables ? I am trying to google it but haven't found any related result

Thanks

Updated:

```
Table names : prod_rugs, prod_furniture, prod_accessories, prod_generic.

Colum names : color, size and (I want to know all the column names that exisits in all above mentioned table)
```

I do not need the value of color or size... i need to know which fields are common among these tables

Comment: I think you didn't get my question. I need to know the common field names not the values. color is just an example. I don't know hwo many common fields i have.

Comment: At the risk of asking a stupid question, how do pants differ from shirts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you may use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` for that:

```
SELECT 
  column_name, 
  table_name 
FROM 
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
  table_schema='test' 
GROUP BY 
  column_name 
HAVING 
  count(1)>1
```

You should replace `test` to name of your database, or course. Query above will result in column names and table names, which occur more than once - so, more, than in one table (because, obviously, one table can not have column with same name more than once)

If you want some specific table & columns name, then add corresponding condition:

```
SELECT 
  column_name, 
  table_name 
FROM 
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
  -- database name:
  table_schema='test' &&
  -- table names:
  table_name IN (
    'prod_rugs', 
    'prod_furniture', 
    'prod_accessories', 
    'prod_generic'
  ) &&
  -- column names:
  column_name IN (
    'color', 
    'size'
  )
GROUP BY 
  column_name 
HAVING 
  count(1)>1
```

Comment: I'm not really sure if he ask this, though it could be interpreted this way

Comment: Hm, _Is there any query for getting column names that exist in multiple tables ?_ - so that's how I interpreted that request

Comment: what should i write inplace of column_name ?

Comment: Nothing. The query _will lookup_ column names. So it's your issue to search such columns (as long as I've understood it correctly)

Comment: Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'stg_homebrandUSA' in 'where clause'

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0.004 sec
---------------------------------------------------

Comment: So then you should specify which query fails (query above has nothing to do with specific column name)

Comment: stg_homebrandUSA i my db name i put it in place of 'test'

Comment: You should enclose it in quotes, it's a string literal

Comment: I got some results but i dont think i was askin this ...this is something going above my head ... let me update my question to be more specific with table names

Answer (score 0):

You need to use sql join to do this.Check this link
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp